# Bootstrap examples with meteor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Im using the bootstrap examples with Meteor (fluid.html). I've updated my bootstrap to the latest 2.0.4.

However I'm having an odd problem with the `padding-top: 60px;` conflicting in the wrong way with

```
@media (max-width: 979px)
    body {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

and well.. webkit seems to do this (only on Meteor for some reason):

[image]

It ends up looking like this:

[image]

(Theres a gap at the top above the black bar) - Of course this is the fluid layout so the browser needs to be dragged down to small view (for iPhones/Androids/Tablets)

How would I manage to get the browser to take `padding-top: 0` as the preference so It doesn't do this? Or why is it doing this (the css files are loaded in the same order - first `bootstrap.css` and then `bootstrap-responsive.css`. I can't figure out the difference

(its supposed to be like this: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html)

Comment: Check the `navbar-fixed-top` class of your `.navbar`

Comment: The `div` has both `navbar` and `navbar-fixed-top`

Comment: Ive pretty much used the exact code as the example. Its meteor interfering somehow

Comment: use Chrome Dev tools or Google Firebug to diagnose which CSS rule/file is responsible..

Comment: The screenshot is from dev tools, it seems that its taking preference on the `<style>` tagged class over the override supposed to be given by `bootstrap-responsive.css`, though I cant figure out what meteor is doing because this is exactly as it is in the example on bootstrap's own site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrading to 2.0.4 I still had the issue where at certain resolutions content would get hidden when using `navbar-fixed-top`. This is what happens at certain resolutions:

[image: Content get hidden under navbar]

After tweaking the CSS I came up with the following which fixes it at all resolutions when added to the top of my CSS file:

```
@media (min-width: 979px) { body { padding-top: 60px; } }
```

[image: Padding adjusts properly with the proper media query]

Hopefully this will sort out your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does not just do this...

[image]

It does more than that. You should inspect what `padding-top` is set to instead, go through the whole panel and see what is setting it, this should tell you where the problem lies. In a really worst case you could use `padding-top: 0 !important;` although it should be known that `!important` is bad advice and you should be able to get around not having to add that.

I don't see how Meteor is responsible as they don't add in any major CSS changes as far as I am aware of; but it might be that there is, but you can only tell if you look where `padding-top` is set.

Comment: I think i've found the issue. Meteor arranges the order of stylesheets in a slightly different way to the example. It's supposed to be 
1) `bootstrap.css`
2) `<style>...</style>`
3) `bootstrap-responsive.css`

But the css is all done at once with meteor so I guess i'll have to go with a manual fix.

Comment: @Akshat: Where does the `style` tag come from? If you just create a `.css` that would load after bootstrap. If you are, however, not using the bootstrap smart package; then you can arrange the order of the stylesheets by either using directories to separate them or changing the filenames to be alphabetically in the order they need to be loaded. Order is indeed a small problem...

Comment: These are all copied from the example. Its where the padding came from. I will try the alphabetical load.

Comment: Alphabetically wont work because both bootstrap packages would load before my css.. It would have to load before bootstrap's packages

Comment: In order to override bootstrap's behavior, wouldn't your css have to come after bootstrap's packages?

Comment: It needs to be before because bootstrap needs to override it (if the page size is less than 979px width (with bootstrap-responsive.css)).